# How to append views in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, append

I did a web app for the meteo in jQuery and HTML/CSS and I appended the days of the week with that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RCZ.png)

And now I would like to do the same in React native but I don't know how to append Views in react native

Has somebody an idea about this ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Killian! Please include your code directly in the question in text format instead of linking to external images.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! For the record, in the future, please keep all the images attached to the post and make sure that you add more code to your question. It makes it easier to help.

Anyway, if I understood you correctly, one thing you could do is:

```
let components = [];

components.push(<View></View>);

render(){
  return(components)
}
```

That should work and you can "append" views.

As for the text that is pretty much like any JS app. You can do this:

```
<Text>`Days ${days}`</Text>
```

To understand this I suggest you read the get started guide for react and react native.